# How can I get the Facebook API return some response as JSON?

Tags: json, facebook, api, deserialization

I'm trying to get some data from the Facebook API and it's returning the result as plain text.

for example: Please give me an access token...

endpoint: `oauth/access_token` 
response content-type: `plain/text`
response content: `access_token=CAA......m0&expires=48280`

How can I get the access token data to be returned as some json (or even xml, if i have to).

**NOTE**: I tried setting a *request* header: `"Content-Type", "application/json"`. Still didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, But you should **never ever** give your extended access token even if it has a limited permissions. Also, except this end point(which returns `plain/text` due to its design) mostly all the end points return in JSON. So could you just give example of any other end point?

Comment: The public/private are part of a demo public sample code i have, so yeah .. don't care about the access token going public. Um, some of the other endpoints like /me (or whatever it is when u get the user info, given an access token) return json.

Comment: Ok, well no issue on the Access Token then, also as far as the API goes, mostly everything is returned as JSON except a few exception here and there like `oauth/access_token` or response to `HTTP DELETE` on `post_ID` and we can do nothing about it

Comment: ta mate. i was REALLY afraid you were going to say that :( much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So far (as of me posting this answer), it looks like Facebook don't give us the option to get certain api endpoints, as json.

`/oauth/access_token` is one of these :(